# Searching by ID with Elasticsearch not returning

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, kibana, nest

I have a controller that contains a method to retrieve data based off it's ID using NEST. On the CLI of Kibana, I grab the ID that it is displayed and paste that into the swagger web app to see if it will populate but it does not (returns a 204).

Swagger (asp.net core web api)

[image]

In my GET method I first attempted it by using SearchAsync but it did not work, so I switched over to GetAsync but still not getting it to work. Not sure why this is not working if in my model class I have all the properties created to match the `_source` in line 22 in the CLI screenshot. **Does anyone have any reason behind why it is not returning what I need it to do and just displaying a 204?**

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<EsSource> Get(String id)
        {
            /* var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
                  .Index("elastic-search-app-logs*")
                  .Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.TimeStamp).Query(id))));*/

            var response = await _elasticClient.GetAsync<EsSource>(new DocumentPath<EsSource>(
               new Id(id)), x => x.Index("elastic-search-app-logs*"));

            return response?.Source;
        }
```

My models class

```
namespace ESPractice.Models
{
    public class EsSource
    {
        public String TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public String Level { get; set; }
        public String MessageTemplate { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class EsExceptions 
    {
        public String Depth { get; set; }
        public String ClassName { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }
        public String Source { get; set; }
        public String StackTraceString { get; set; }
        public String RemoteStackTraceString { get; set; }
        public String RemoteStackIndex { get; set; }
        public String HResult { get; set; }
        public String HelpURL { get; set; }
    }

    public class EsFields
    {
        public String SourceContext { get; set; }
        public String ActionId { get; set; }
        public String ActionName { get; set; }
        public String RequestId { get; set; }
        public String RequestPath { get; set; }
        public String ConnectionId { get; set; }
        public String MachineName { get; set; }
        public String Environment { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply your call with `await _client.GetAsync<EsSource>(id, x => x.Index("elastic-search-app-logs*"));`

You can also enable debug so you will receive detailed information about what was sent to elasticsearch and what was the response as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html).

If you want to debug a single call you can do (make sure it's not enabled for production)

```
var response = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r
        .DisableDirectStreaming() 
    )
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

Check `response.DebugInformation` for more details.